# Facebook Javascript SDK Login Demo Error

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am learning to use Facebook's Javascript SDK for web login. I am playing around with this demo example: https://gist.github.com/heldrida/6232556

However, I get the following error message when trying to log in:

> "Invalid Scopes: read_stream, publish_stream, read_friendlists. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions"

Can someone please explain what this means? Thanks.

Comment: These permissions have been removed, they don’t exist any more in the current API version.

Answer (score 0):

Apps on Facebook must be submitted to Review Team for the app to request these permission listed. In future, if your app requires them, you must submit the app for approval. The message is pretty straight forward, the warning is shown on users whom have roles in the app For now, if your app doesn't need them, remove `scope` argument from `FB.login()`

```
    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {

        // handle the response
        console.log("Response goes here!");

        }, {scope: 'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,read_friendlists'});            
    }
```

to

```
    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {

        // handle the response
        console.log("Response goes here!");

        });          
    }
```